# cannot do an ldapdelete: Strong(er) authentication required (8)

Tags: ldap, authentication, openldap, utilities

I'm fairly new to ldap and i'm trying to delete a ldap object. (i haven't set up SSL yet.) i use the command

```
ldapdelete -x 'dc=example,dc=com' 'cn=AnUser'
```

it gives me the error

```
ldap_delete: Strong(er) authentication required (8)
additional info: modifications require authentication
```

Does this mean i can't delete using simple authentication? (I can delete using ldapscripts but i really want to use only the ldap-utils)

EDIT:

```
I tried doing and ldapdelete -x -W 'dc=example,dc=com' 'cn=AnUser'
```

but it gives me a `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)` error, but i'm sure the password is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax you want is:

ldapdelete -xW -D 'your account dn' 'object to delete'